# How make SL in oracle forms?

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I want to make Serial No in oracle Forms according details table entry record in tabular form.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Unfortunately, your question is not very clear. Please re-read the FAQ and [edit] your question with more concrete information to turn it into a [MCVE]

Comment: Maybe you should  check for the word "Sequence" in your SQL manauls ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this problem. 
Solution:

- Create new item in on details datablock.
- Go property pallet of this item.
- Select Formula column
- Enter formula :System.Cursor_Record  `:System.Cursor_Record`